# How do you prevent disturbing a wooden fence when digging a foundation?

Tags: foundation, fence, excavation, trench

When digging a foundation beside a wooden fence, how can I ensure my excavation doesn't cause the fence to collapse?

I'm digging into chalky ground and the foundations will be around 450mm wide and 450mm deep. The fence is about 1/2 meter away from the trench edge. I don't know how deep the fence posts are dug in the ground.

Comment: 450mm wide and 450mm deep? Are they post supports?

Comment: What do you mean by "chalky ground"? Mostly soil with some chalk bits? Or solid chalk and little loose stuff? Or chalk and lots of flint (of various sizes from stones to f Big "boulders"?

Answer (score 2):

You can tie the fence posts off in each direction with rope and stakes to keep it from moving back and forth. You could also support it just on one side with 2x4's nailed into stakes in the ground. Did this setting power poles all the time.

Answer (score 0):

A good operator of the digger might be able to do it, but it will be touchy depending on the ground and size/height) of the fence. Probably not a good job for a first timer on the machine.

Depending on how much you want to keep the fence intact, it might be better to dismantle the fence first.

Would not need to worry about the weather turning nasty when the ground is weaken.